# Assistance required with ASP.NET compilation error

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, compilation

I have an intermittent compilation error on an ASP.NET File System website that I have created in Visual studio 2005, using C# as the language and running on the ASP.NET development server.

This website usually compiles with no problems/errors. However, the page containing a FileUpload control (which works correctly most of the time) will sometimes fail compilation with this error:

**Compilation error CS0117: 'FileUpload' does not contain a definition for 'HasFile'**

I have checked everything I can think of to resolve this problem, including re-adding the control to the aspx page, checking for the correct using/namespace declarations, checking the code behind syntax to declare/use the FilUpload control etc. But to no avail.

When I have been patient enough to continually re-compile the site it will eventually compile. Sometimes this is immediate, but can take literally dozens of attempts.

Can anyone offer advice on this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I thought that problem was fixed with sp1. I used to see it but after vs2005sp1 I never saw it again.  Do you have the service packs installed?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had considered that as a possible issue, however I'm currently using Visual studio 2005, with Microsoft.NET Framework Version 2.0 SP2.

Comment: Do you have this [VS 2005 sp1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb4a75ab-e2d4-4c96-b39d-37baf6b5b1dc) installed?  There is a different one if you have vista btw.

Comment: Yes, I am currently running  Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1(KB926601) on XP service pack 3. Thank you for the assistance so far.

Comment: Only other thing i can recommend would be to try and recreate the page.  Rename the page to something like FileUploadOld.aspx.  Then copy and paste your aspx markup into a new page.   Let VS rebuild the designer.  I have never had this issue with vs2008 or 2010 but remember them well from 2005

Comment: I shall attempt that now, if that does not work, I'm thinking of installing visual web developer express 2010 to see if that eliminates the issue. Thank you Chad, you've been most helpful.

Comment: Are you sure the site is running the correct worker process version?

Comment: This can sometimes happen if you have optimizeCompilations="true" on the compilation element in your web.config - can you check whether this is the case?  Setting it to false will slow down your compilation *marginally* but should ensure that the problem goes away.